# CummeRBund how to add color in scatter plot

Tags: r

How can I add color in a scatter plot?

```
library(cummeRbund)
cuff<-readCufflinks()

s<-csScatter(genes(cuff), smooth=T)
```

Comment: Here is the docs for this function. http://artax.karlin.mff.cuni.cz/r-help/library/cummeRbund/html/csScatter.html. From what I see it does not have a color attribute, but I think it inherits one from ggplot object